# How to reduce Execution time ?? Should I use functions or remain with the idea of nested loops

Tags: c

I have to reduce execution time in this code. In this problem the value of n may go upto 10^8 . And hence i think nested loops are not that good because it is very laggy for large data's . So I was wondering if I use a function instead of the inner loop . Will this idea work for reduction of execution time??
or it will be the same case even if i use funtions??

```
#include <stdio.h>
long long a[500001]={0};
int main()
{
long long n,i,j,flag,sum=0,temp,count=0;

scanf("%lld",&n);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    if(a[j]>=a[i])
        count++;
     flag=a[i]*(count);
     if(flag>sum)
        sum=flag;
     count=0;
}
printf("%lld",sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use *more efficient algorithm* and it may not depend on functions.

Comment: If `n` goes up to 100,000,000 why have you declared a with a lower number?

Comment: u need a more efficient data structure.

Comment: Functions and loops are different constructs for different problems. You are comparing apples and bananas (oranges are still too close to apples - both are round).

Comment: okay got it my algorithm is not efficient

Comment: and functions will not make a difference ain't it?

Comment: and why do i get so many negatives for this question was this a stupid doubt??

Comment: Please describe conceptually what this code is supposed to do.  Then someone might be able to suggest a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is the algorithm:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
```

You have here O(n^2), so this is very complex algorithm.

Can you explain what do you want to get with that code?

### An improved solution

1) [sort your data](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) from higher to lower value O(n) or O(n*log(n))
2) Use this algorithm:

```
 int max=0,tmp=0;
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      tmp=array[i]*(i+1);
      if(max<tmp) max=tmp;
  }
```

#### Example

Input: 4 30 20 53 14

1) Array = {53,30,20,14,4}
2)

```
    tmp     | max | iteration  
    0       |0    | 0  
    53      |53   | 1  
  30*2=60   |60   | 2  
  20*3=60   |60   | 3  
  14*4=56   |60   | 4  
  4*5=20    |60   | 5
```

Output:60

#### Complexity

if sort is O(n*log(n)) and my algorithm is O(n) you get an O(n*log(n)) complexity.
[image]

Comment: How do you find complexity . Can you suggest a website from where i can learn to find complexity. or you can tell it here?

Comment: But BTW your solution may take more time cause you need to first sort the data and then you will find the sum . This may take more time i think so what are your opinions?

Comment: @user5910213 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o) you can find information about time complexity. When you use Big o (O), you only have to get the slowest operation. Because if you have two operations, one O(n) and the other O(n^2), when n takes large values, n<<<<<n^2 so you can do this:
n^2 + n ~= n*n   when n takes large values (or ∞)

Comment: I am saying that will your code not take too much time 
because you need to sort the elements first then further